# Azure search- using lucene and filters

Tags: azure, search, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I want to perform an Azure search on a location index (comprising of 100K records of countryCode and location information)

The need is to

```
a) limit the search to specified country codes
b) be able to handle fuzzy search
```

I am able to achieve filtered search in simple query syntax using odata syntax on 
$filter=(countrycode eq 'IN' or countrycode eq 'AT' or countrycode eq 'AU')
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search

I am able to achieve fuzzy search using Lucene search by
queryType=full&search=euroe~1
as per this syntax

queryType=full&search=sydne~1&$filter=CountryCode eq 'AT' or CountryCode eq 'AU' &searchMode=All

Is there a way to use a contains instead of multiple eq. The syntax seems to be limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax for set containment in Azure Search. If this feature is important to you, please add an item to [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) to help the Azure Search team prioritize.

Comment: thanks- will do. We have scenarios where based on context, we need to apply country filters- and seems clunky to create the filters through multiple or statements on each of the filter parameter

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but what about `search.in`?

Your request could be:

```
queryType=full&search=sydne~1&$filter=search.in(CountryCode, 'AT, AU')&searchMode=All
```

You can find more info on [OData expression syntax for Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search)